# git: --prune-empty after using bfg duplicates commits

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

I am using [bfg](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to remove some subdirectories from a (clone of) git repository:

```
java -jar bfg-1.12.12.jar --delete-folders {folder1,folder2,folder3} --no-blob-protection myrepo.git/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

This works OK but after I have used bfg I have many empty commits (i.e. commits with nice log messages but without changes because they only touched files that have been removed now).

So as next step I tried to use

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'git_commit_non_empty_tree "$@"' HEAD
```

or

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Both versions do not have the desired effect (removing empty commits).

Instead what I end up with is a repository where (see screenshot below, left is before pruning, right is after):

1. a few empty commits have been removed
2. most empty commits remain
3. non-empty commits are duplicated in separate trains of commits

[image]

Any advise?

Comment: How did you create `myrepo.git` - is it a bare/mirror repository per the BFG guidelines?

Comment: I used `git clone --mirror
https://:@git....`. Is that the correct way?

Comment: Yes. Did you also push back to and refetch your `origin` before starting with `filter-branch`?

Comment: No, I did not -- and as the "in-house solution" (using bfg-repo-cleaner) works in one go, I won't bother to check if that would have worked I guess...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the duplicate history you are seeing, it seems likely that your post-BFG-run attempt to remove the old, now-rewritten commit-history has failed.  This could occur for a number of reasons, but the main one is if `myrepo.git` is not a bare/mirror-clone repo as outlined in the BFG instructions.

Something is retaining the old, pre-BFG rewrite history, which now shows as a duplicate.  It is possible or even likely that this history is stored in a remote such as `origin`, and this would also explain why your `filter-branch` is not removing all the empty commits you expect.

Finally, you may be interested in a current pull-request to [add the `--prune-empty-commits` feature to BFG](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/pull/147) - it works well and as with everything BFG, is orders of magnitude faster than running `filter-branch`.

Comment: Which revision did you try to build? Latest in that PR 52a2ae7 should be fine, maybe you built an older version. If that rev isn't building, leave a note on the PR.

Comment: After double-checking that I check-out the correct version it compiles fine. (Sorry, first time I tried to compile a pull request from github.)

Comment: It also seems to work much better than the `git filter-branch` solution. There remain a few annoying (empty) "Merge branch 'master' of ..." but otherwise the history is clean.

Comment: How did you solve this @fuenfundachtzig? I had a similar situation but I don't get it how to let one master branch: [link](https://ibb.co/kLchVw)